# (PHP) HOW TO STORE THE NAME ATTRIBUTE IN DB INSTEAD OF VALUE

Tags: php, mysql, api

I want to store the text selected from my dropdown instead of value attribute in option tag. I just used API library by the way. Thanks a lot!
[image: HELLO,]

Comment: just remove all the value tags (If there is no value your text will be used). Next time please do NOT post code as images

Comment: Okay next time I'm sorry. Thanks but the API automatically gives the value for the specific items in dropdown

Comment: Please do not post images for code or output(if possible), posting them as text with markup allows others to try your code out or at least copy it to post as part of comments or answer.

Comment: yes, and im sorry next time i will not. thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

To get the of name attribute,
consider your using vanilla js.

In your event listener you can do some thins like this

```
let value = document.querySelector('#id_of_select').getAttribute('name');
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir for the response. I'll try it. Thank you!!!! <3

Comment: Hi it's not working for me :(